# Asynchronous cuBLAS calls

Tags: asynchronous, cuda, cublas

I want to make calls to cuBLAS routines asynchronously. Is it possible? If yes, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `cublasSetStream` function before the cublas calls.

`cublasSetStream(cublasHandle, cudaStream)`;

Comment: But I am not using the handle in any of my gemv and gemm calls so will it work then also?

Comment: In the new cublas api this function was changed to `cublasSetKernelStream(cudaStream)`

Comment: It's not clear looking at documentation if you only need a single non-default stream or if you should use a stream for each computation you want to happen asynchronously.

Comment: The function is now simply `cublasSetStream(handle, streamId)`